# transformer 3 taps in the primary

Tags: transformer

[image]
This is a transformer that puts out 13vdc.It has a built in bridge. There are three taps on the primary, which ones connect to a/c?  this is going to power a dc motor. Thanks for your help

Comment: What other information do you have on this part? It doesn't look like it has a bridge built in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a step down transformer with turns ratio (N:1);
Try randomly applying low voltage (e.g.; 10mV at appropriate frequency) AC and measure signals at other pins by using an oscilloscope. When you see N times amplified version of your input signal (i.e.; 10NmV), the pins you see the amplified AC are the primary windings. Now, apply a higher test voltage (e.g.; 10V) to the primary windings. The other pins are from secondary winding; observe the voltage levels on them to find out the tapping scheme.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datasheet or part number for the transformer it should specify how to connect the primary.

It's likely that the primary is tapped for different input voltages, and you would use one tap  to connect to a given voltage AC source, like 120VAC like we have here in the States. Maybe another tap for 100VAC in Japan, and  the whole winding to connect to a higher voltage AC source like 240VAC in Europe. (For example.)

You can use an ohmmeter to get an idea of how the taps are configured, but the datasheet is really the key here.

Comment: Cant seem to find a spec sheet.  I should have specified that the 4 pins are marked as the dc voltage only 2 of those pins are used.  I dont understand why there are three a/c pins. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you need the data sheet.

If you're really desperate, though, and are willing to risk fireworks, I suggest you take an ohmmeter to those 4 pins. I suspect that you will find that you don't have a single winding with 3 taps. You probably have 2 independent windings with identical resistances. Generally, these allow operation at 110 or 120. For 110, you connect the two windings in parallel. For 220, connect them in series.